# Multiple queries in database PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to make a pages where you can see all product images (that has already succeeded look below in products.php) and all categories.

But how can i make a second query? Is that possible in one connection?

The query for the list of categories must be:

```
SELECT category_name FROM categories
```

And in php something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo("<li>");
    echo($row["categorie_name"])
    echo("</li>"); 
}
```

How can I make this in one connection or is this impossible?

db_config.php

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'sopranos');
?>
```

db_open.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
?>
```

db_close.php

```
<?php
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

products.php

```
<?php
    include('db_config.php');

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM products ";
    $query .= "WHERE product_category =";
    $query .= $_GET["cat"];

    include(db_open.php');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
        <div class="product">
            <img alt="product details" src="images/product_
                <?php echo($row['product_id']) ?>
           .jpg" /> 
       </div>
       <?php
    }
    include(db_close.php');       
?>
```

Comment: What is a whereinner?

Comment: Yes. Just run the second query the same way as the first before calling `mysql_close()`. Also, strongly consider learning to use PDO or MySQLi since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by the same connection ?

If you mean doing two queries separately in the same page, then yes you can do this by connecting to the database one time, using db_open.php, then here's how you create the queries:

```
$first_query = mysql_query("Select * from table1"); 
while($first_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($first_query){
//code goes here
}

$second_query = mysql_query("Select * from table2"); 
while($second_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($second_query){
//code goes here
}
```

However, if you mean running two queries in the same connection (preventing the db access time penalty), it depends on the engine your using MYISAM or INNODB, but in your case you are just running 2 select queries which will not affect the page load speed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating a new variable `$query` and then  adding on your `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` this `&&` that would look like this `while ((($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) && (($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) )` ?